# How can I get stateId from cascading dropdown List

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

Here I'm using Mvc with JQUERY please Help me How can I get State_Id from state dropdownList

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SaveEmployee", "Customer", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal" }))
{ 
<b>Country</b>            
    @Html.DropDownListFor(cnt => cnt.SaveEmployee.Cnt_Id, new SelectList(Model.GetCountry, "Cnt_Id", "Cnt_Name"),"Select Country")
<b>State</b> <select id="DDlState" class="form-control"></select>
```

Here When my Country Drp change its fetching State values But when i click on Submit btn I'm is not able 2 bind stateId

**JqueryCode**

```
var ddlStates = $('#DDlState');
ddlStates.append($('<option/>', { value: "-1", text: "Please Select State" }))
 $.ajax({
   url: 'http://localhost:47237/Customer/GetStateById/' + stsId,
   method: 'GET',
   dataType: 'Json',
   // data:stsId,
 }).success(function (data) {
   console.log(data);
   $.each(data,function (i,Items) {
     $(ddlStates).append($('<option/>', { value: Items.Sts_Id, text: Items.Sts_Name }))
     ddlStates.attr('disabled', false);
 })
```

Comment: This is awful code (no strong type binding for the 2nd dropdownlist, no validation, no ability to return the view, cannot be used for editing existing data, etc etc). Suggest you study the code in [this DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1bPZym) to understand how to code cascading dropdownlists

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thanks a lot for ur value-able feed back

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please Provide

```
<select id="DDlState" class="form-control" name="SaveEmployee.Sts_Id"></select>
```

I hope it will work